# python jumpssh from win with nix jumphost, key file "path not found" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ssh

I'm having issue: want to run command on nix server from Win using nix jump host. Conn to jumphost is successful, but then receive error that key file path not found for connection to remote host. if I don't provide key that should work by my understanding of documentation:

```
:param private_key_file: local path to a private key file to use if key needed for authentication and not present in standard path (~/.ssh/)
```

, because that's where my key is. Additionally - if I run commands with gateway session.run_cmd(), I can get output, list dir, ensure the key file is there and even cat and receive it's contents. Here is the example code that gives error (for test replace with your users and hosts):

```
import os
from jumpssh import SSHSession

kp = "path to jumphost key"
kf = os.path.join("c:", os.path.sep, kp)
print(kf)
gwhost = 'jump host(NIX) ip'
host = 'remote host(NIX) ip'
user = 'user name(same on both)'
# also tried ~ and no file at all, because key in default location
# and then according to docs - not required
kfu = '/home/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa'
print(kfu)

gateway_session = SSHSession(gwhost, user, private_key_file = kf).open()
remote_session = gateway_session.get_remote_session(host, username=user, private_key_file = kfu)

print(remote_session.get_cmd_output('ls -lta'))
```

Comment: additionally tested from NIX host - same error - total confusion - was thinking win-nix cross-env problem

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help someone :) there is the gotcha - I never found it in docs, but figured out through debugging - library expects to have all keys available on the machine that runs script, even docs tell you that key param can even be omitted if it's in default location where I obviously have it on my jump-host for user that normally uses it from there :D